# Ocultar columna automaticamente de una tabla dinamica HTML con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema con mi tabla dinamica, necesito que no sea visible una columna, al cargar la pagina no se muestra esa columna pero al seleccionar los filtros que son fecha y cliente, pinto con Javascript los datos de mi tabla y muestra la columna que oculto en el HTML

Para ocultar en HTML uso Data-visible = "False" y funciona pero al momento de cargar los datos no

El CÓDIGO ES ESTE

```js
InsertaRenglon: function(item, index, arr) {
  var table = document.getElementById("tblInventarioId");
  var row = table.tBodies[0].insertRow();
  row.id = "tc" + item.Descripcion;
  var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
  cell0.innerHTML = item.Descripcion;
  cell1.innerHTML = item.NumeroDeParte;
  cell2.innerHTML = item.AlmacenId;
  cell3.innerHTML = item.AlmacenDesc;
  cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-control input-sm jsTrim jsNumber' name='type' id='txt" +
    item.NumeroDeParte + "' value='" + item.Cantidad + "' style='width:50px '>";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="tblInventarioId" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered display compact" style="font-size: small" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-width="8%">Descripción</th>
          <th data-width="8%">Número de Parte</th>
          <th data-width="8%" data-visible="false">Almacén Id</th>
          <th data-width="8%">Almacén</th>
          <th data-width="8%">Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbInventarios"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si colocas el ejemplo completo en el cual podemos ejecutar el código y ver la tabla obtendrías antes la respuesta a tu problema. Por favor coloca el html asociado así nos colaboras a la hora de poder depurar tu código